# Is fixing the mqconfig parameters to suit the OS requirement is under the scope of an MQ Admin activity

Tags: ibm-mq

Is fixing the `mqconfig` parameters to suit the OS requirement(SunOS) is under the scope of an MQ Admin activity or UNIX. below is the output of our mq server which is failing  to meet the OS requirements.

MQ Version is `7.1.0.6` and OS is `SunOS dbkpembf042 5.10 Generic_150400-46 sun4v sparc sun4v`

```
$ /opt/mqm/bin/mqconfig -v 7.1
mqconfig: Analyzing Solaris 10 (sparc) settings for WebSphere MQ V7.1

mqconfig: You do not have a group.mqm project configured.  IBM recommends
          that you configure a group.mqm project with resource limits for
          WebSphere MQ, but you can run queue managers under other projects.
          If you plan to use a different project for WebSphere MQ, rerun
          mqconfig with the -p option to analyze that project.
mqconfig: No project given.  Analyzing all projects with queue manager
          activity (default).


Project default (): System V Semaphores
  max-sem-ids         13 of 128 sets             (10%)   IBM>=1024         FAIL

Project default (): System V Shared Memory
  max-shm-ids         143 of 128 sets            (111%)  IBM>=1024         FAIL
  max-shm-memory      68585259008 bytes                  IBM>=4294967296   PASS

Project default (): Other Settings
  max-file-descriptor 256 descriptors                    IBM>=10000        FAIL


Shell Default Options (mqm)
  ksh                 bgnice:off                         IBM:off           PASS
```

Also what are the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your organization is setup. You need root access to alter the `/etc/project` file in Solaris. So basically that is a task for a Unix Administrator. Since it's MQ related you could get root access for a limited period of time to alter the `/etc/project` file.

---

To set the correct values alter the `/etc/project` file to:

```
group.mqm:[gid*]:Websphere MQ:::process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,10000,deny);project.max-sem-ids(priv,1024);project-shm-ids=(priv,1024,deny)
```

gid* is the group id if your mqm group as defined in the /etc/group file.
you could also set higher values depending on your needs.

---

Find detailed description of the system resources in the IBM MQ v7.1 Knowledge Center page "[Additional settings for installing on Solaris systems](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sq10360_.htm)"

---

Example below will use the Solaris `projadd` command to added the entry to the `/etc/project` file:

```
projadd -c "WebSphere MQ default settings" \
        -K "process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,10000,deny)" \
        -K "project.max-shm-ids=(priv,1024,deny)" \
        -K "project.max-sem-ids=(priv,1024,deny)" group.mqm
```

Comment: Did that answer your question ? or do you also need to know what values to set in the project file ?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I have root access. Could you please suggest me on what are the  'mqconfig' parameters to be set for tuning MQ7.1.0.6 on sunOS.  below are the details of our current settings from /etc/project.    _$ cat project
system:0::::process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,10000,deny);project.max-shm-ids=(priv,1024,deny);project.max-sem-ids=(priv,1024,deny)
user.root:1::::
noproject:2::::
default:3::::
group.staff:10::::_

Comment: I've altered the answer to show the resource parameters.

Comment: Great answer.  I updated to include the link to the 7.1 KC instead of 7.0.1 KC.  I also added an example using the Solaris `projadd` command instead of manually updating the `/etc/project` file.

Comment: @JoshMc: Thx for inputs.  I do not see 'group.mqm' project. and pls confirm the link you shared is applicable for SunOS 5.10 bcoz in the link it states about SunOS10 and later. In order to proceed with altering of /etc/project or using 'projectadd' I need group.mqm created. I'm not sure of the consequences if I create group.mqm now and not sure why the setup is like this in our env.# cat /etc/project
system:0::::process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,10000,deny);project.max-shm-ids=(priv,1024,deny);project.max-sem-ids=(priv,1024,deny)
user.root:1
noproject:2
default:3
group.staff:10

Comment: SunOS 5.10 is know as Solaris 10 (you drop the "5."). The entry in `/etc/project` for `group.mqm` corresponds to the unix group `mqm` which you would already have and would not need to add any group.  Running the `projectadd` command will add the `group.mqm` entry for you to `/etc/project`.

Comment: @JoshMc: Thanks for your inputs. Based on my current mqconfig params which are failed, could you please give me the details which I need to execute using `projectadd` command.

Comment: The `projadd` command that I added at the end of the post by @crashdog which will add those three failed params for you.